# Select Tag blank value - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to bind a property to the `select` tag. But everytime I select an option, it changes the property value but leaves the `select` value blank.

[Here's how it looks like.](https://i.imgur.com/zBQYbrs.gifv)

**HTML**

```html
<div>
  <label for="base">Base</label>
  <select (change)="getLatest(selected)" [(ngModel)]="selected" ngOptions>
    <option *ngFor="let currency of currencies" value="{{currency}}">{{currency}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<h2>{{response.base}}   {{response.date}}</h2>
```

**TS**

```js
    export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(private ratesService: RatesService) { }
    
      response = {
        'base': null,
        'date': null,
        'rates': {
          null: null
        }
      };
    
      currencies: string[] = Object.keys(this.response.rates);
    
      selected = 'EUR';
    
      getLatest(base?: string): void {
        this.ratesService.getLatest(base).subscribe(response => {
          this.response = response;
          this.currencies = Object.keys(response.rates).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
        });
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.getLatest();
      }
    }
```

PS: service returns rest from fixer.io/latest

Comment: try to set "#selected" to "select" and then pass to function "selected.value"

Comment: @Sergey it stops from disappearing value but now it doesn't change property value (function is not called)

Answer (score 1):

Each time you select a new option you invoke `getLatest`, and inside that method you change the value of `this.currencies` which is the same object used to create the `select` options in the first place, so Angular needs to create fresh options for that new array, none of which are selected yet.

To fix this:

- Is this method `this.ratesService.getLatest(base)` expected to return a new list of currencies? And:
- Do you need to update the list of currencies every time you select a new option?

Seem to me that updating `this.currencies` needs to be done only once, in the `ngOnInit` method, so you should remove `(change)="getLatest(selected)"` from your template file. Whatever you wanted to accomplish with that `(change)=...` should invoke a different method, not `getLatest`

Comment: It is the problem. I've created a hardcoded array of currencies and it is working. Yet it doesn't look like a optimal solution.

Comment: @karoluS, the only problem is if the value selected is not in the response you received. So, I think there are a problem with your this.ratesService.getLatest(base).

Comment: @Eliseo it is in the response {{response.base}} is the same as the selected option all the time. I just don't know how to get option value and pass it to getLatest

Comment: You can add the value after this.currencies=..;this.currencies.Add(base) ;

Comment: i understand but it returns a different set of currencies everytime because when you select i.e EUR it returns all the others but EUR.

Comment: So you want to remove from the valid options of the `select`, exactly the option that you want to be selected? Though you possibly could use a `*ngIf` to remove one of the options and get away with it, can you explain why you want to remove the selected option from the valid options? That's not how a `select` is expected to be used, so you're likely to encounter more issues down the road.